# VBA adding colors to all tables within a word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a document with multiple tables. I would like to color the header of the tables who have those words in them to a certain color. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link below your question to add the code you have to the question, itself. Code does not format properly in comments, making it almost impossible to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each table in the document, test a value in a cell and shade when it matches:

```
Dim t As Table
For Each t In ActiveDocument.Tables
    If t.Cell(1,1) = "something" Then t.Rows(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorGray50
Next
```

Comment: Here is my code:Sub SNAP_test()
'
' SNAP_test Macro
'
'
Dim t As Table
For Each t In ActiveDocument.Tables
    If t.Cell(1, 1) = "STATE PROFILE" Then t.Rows(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorGreen70
    If t.Cell(1, 1) = "The SNAP Timeliness Study" Then t.Rows(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorBlue70
Next
End Sub

Comment: `t.Cell(1,1).Range.Text`

Comment: Sub SNAP_test()
'
' SNAP_test Macro
'
'
Dim t As Table
For Each t In ActiveDocument.Tables
    If t.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "STATE PROFILE:" Then t.Rows(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorDarkGreen
    If t.Cell(1, 2) = "The SNAP Timeliness Study" Then t.Rows(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorDarkBlue
Next

End Sub     the code is  not running

Comment: The text in a table cell also includes a 2-character "end of cell" marker, so try something like `.Text Like "STATE PROFILE:*"` instead of using `=`

Comment: the code ran but the entire row is shaded blue i want the first row first column to be green and first row second column to be blue

Comment: Well you already know how to refer to the top-left cell so that should be a straight-forward adjustment...